# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS GRUB menu now showing wasn't there before

Tags: 16.04, grub2

I have had my Ubuntu 16.04LTS running great for the last few weeks.

I switch it on today and I have the grub menu, screenshot:

[image: Grub]

This never appeared before, so I selected the top option and it booted to the login screen, logged in okay but nothing other than my desktop appeared, just the folders, no dock, top menu, etc

I restarted, same grub menu, select first option now its fine.

1. How do I make it not show the grub menu as it did before?
2. Why has this happened?

I do have other hard drives installed that contain Ubuntu, but I just have them plugged in so I can see the drive contents.

Comment: *I do have other hard drives installed that contain Ubuntu* is the key. You didn't add the other instance yourself but any kernel update will trigger os-prober, detect the other Ubuntu and add it to the Grub menu.

Comment: It is being detected automatically as explained before. If the second Ubuntu is there only to able to access some (personal) files in it, then I would simply backup those files to somewhere else and format that partition to use it as a simple data partition (then the old files can be moved there again).

Comment: So if I format those drive this should remove the grub menu? If I didn't want to format the drives are there some files I could remove so they aren't detected? (I removed my original comment reply)

Comment: Yes, if now the drive contains only data partition(s), running `sudo update-grub` will then detect only the current Ubuntu and when that is the only OS, the Grub menu typically doesn't show up. I guess it should be possible by removing files but not sure which or how it should be done.